# Adding Sum of Object Attributes to Django Rest Framework Response

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm Trying to add the sum of multiple objects to a DRF response. For example, right now the response works with just listing the objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": "47d0deaa5c8c",
        "amount": "25.00"
    },
    {
        "id": "29787731",
        "amount": "25.00"
    }
]
```

But what I want is to be able to sum the amount attribute of those objects together and then include that in the response, so that it would look like this:

```
{  
   "sum":"50.00",
   "objects":[  
      {  
         "id":"47d0deaa5c8c",
         "amount":"25.00"
      },
      {  
         "id":"29787731",
         "amount":"25.00"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here's my current APIView:

```
class TransactionsList(GenericAPIView):
"""
Retrieve list of transactions
"""

authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def get(self, request):
    """List Transactions"""
    transaction = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer = TransactionSerializer(transaction, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

And Serializer:

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Transaction
    fields = ('id', 'amount')
```

How could I efficiently go about adding the sum field into the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
return Response(serializer.data)
```

to

```
from django.db.models import Sum
all_sum = transaction.aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']
return Response({'sum': all_sum if all_sum else 0 , 'objects': serializer.data})
```

Comment: In your answer, `sum` is the length of `objects`. The OP says, the *aggregated sum*

Answer (score 1):

Since the **`amount`** field seems **`string`** type. So, we've to convert to **`int`** before summing them.

```
class TransactionsList(GenericAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve list of transactions
    """
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        """List Transactions"""
        transaction = Transaction.objects.all()
        serializer = TransactionSerializer(transaction, many=True)
        return_data = {"sum": str(sum([lambda items: int(items['amount'])])), "objects": serializer.data}
        return Response(return_data)
```

If the **amount** field is `int` type, then you don't want to add do the type casting. If so, use this,

```
return_data = {"sum": sum([lambda items: items['amount']]), "objects": serializer.data}
```